# How to link Access 2003 database to a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, ms-access, ms-access-2003

Im building a website that's running on a MySQL database and I need to show a graph based on data that a certain logging system stores in an Access 2003 database. My goal is to link the Access 2003 DB to my MySQL database, so that I can easily get my data from my O/RM (this has many benefits in the current structure of the application).

The problem that i'm running into is that I can only export my Access DB to the MySQL database, but then I don't have a connection with those two, what means that when the Access database gets updated, the MySQL DB doesnt. Is this right ? Isn't there a possibillity to link the Access databases in the MySQL DB ?

I can get them linked when i use the ODBC Connector from MySQL. But i don't know if thats a good option since in that way my datasource is a MySQL one, and thats a bit of a workaround in the current use. (currently the data gets written in the Access Database).

What is your opinion on this and whats the best way to approach this situation ?

Answer (score 0):

go through this [Connect to a MySQL database](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Connect-to-a-MySQL-database-8760c647-88b9-409d-b312-6ea8f84a269b) and [Using Microsoft Access as a Front-end to MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-examples-tools-with-access-linked-tables.html) for link to mysql databse